# Shogun print shogun.MulticlassLabels values

Tags: python, machine-learning, distance, shogun

I wanted to use the mahalanobis distance with LMNN, which is not yet implemented in sklearn.

I try to use the metric-learn library but the LMNN is slow. So, I am looking into [shogun](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/).

I saw this tutorial on [LMNN](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/static/notebook/current/LMNN.html) .
I am using the distance learned in LMNN and using it with the KNN model.

In the [tutorial](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/examples/latest/examples/multiclass_classifier/knn.html), they only explained how to see the accuracy.

`eval = MulticlassAccuracy()
accuracy = eval.evaluate(labels_predict, labels_test)`

But, I want to see the value of the predicted labels.

Answer (score 0):

From the [API](http://shogun.ml/api):

`SGVector<float64_t> CMulticlassLabels::get_labels()` (inherited from `CDenseLabels`)

In your case: `labels_predict.get_labels()`, which will give you a numpy array.